# Merge two columns of a text file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file with several columns of text and values. This structure:

```
CAR       38
     DOG  42
CAT       89
CAR       23
     APE  18
```

If column 1 has a String, column 2 doesn't (or it's actually an emptry String). And the other way around: if column 1 is empty, column 2 has a String. In other words, the "object" (CAR, CAT, DOG etc.) occurs in either column 1 or column 2, but never both.

I'm looking for an efficient way to consolidate column 1 and 2 so that the file looks like this instead:

```
CAR  38
DOG  42
CAT  89
CAR  23
APE  18
```

I can do this in a Bash script by using while and if, but I'm sure there is a simpler way of doing it. Can someone help?

Cheers!
Z

Comment: manual pages for `cut` and `paste` spring to mind.

Comment: `while read; do echo $REPLY; done < file`

Comment: `printf "%s  %s\n" $(< file)`

Comment: @Cyrus: Both commands are clever approaches that work with the sample input data, but aren't _generally_ robust, because they rely on shell expansions that aren't _limited_ to the ones of interest here, with potentially unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
column -t file
```

Output:

```
CAR  38
DOG  42
CAT  89
CAR  23
APE  18
```

Answer (score 8):

Note: If:

- you're looking for output with *auto-sized, left-aligned fixed-width* columns (the longest field value determines the width, with shorter values getting right-padded with spaces)
- and are happy with *two spaces* as the column separator
- and are using *files small enough to read into memory as a whole*,

use [Cyrus's simpler, `column`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29547742/45375).

See below for how the `column`-based approach compares to the `awk`-based approach below in terms of performance and resource consumption.

---

**`awk`** is your friend here:

```
awk -v OFS='  ' '{ print $1, $2 }' file
```

- `awk` splits lines into field by whitespace by default, so, with your input, lines such as `CAR       38` and `DOG  42` are parsed the same (`CAR` and `DOG` become field 1, `$1`, and `38` and `42` become field 2, `$2`).
- `-v OFS='  '` sets the output-field separator to two spaces (default is a single space); note that there'll be no *padding* of output values to create *aligned* output.

To create *aligned* output with fields of varying width, use Awk's `printf` function, which gives you more control over the output; for instance the following outputs a 10-char-wide left-aligned 1st column, and a 2-char-wide right-aligned 2nd column:

```
awk '{ printf "%-10s  %2s\n", $1, $2 }' file
```

- Note that the column widths must be known in advance.
- By contrast, `column -t` conveniently determines the column widths automatically, by parsing all data first, but that has performance and resource-consumption implications; see below.

---

**Performance / resource-consumption comparison** between the `column -t` and the Awk approach:

- `column -t` needs to analyze all input data up front, in a first pass, so as to be able to determine the *maximum* input column widths; from what I can tell, it does so by reading the input *as a whole* into memory first, which can be problematic with large input files.
- By contrast, the Awk solution reads lines one by one - but relies on knowing the column widths ahead of time.

Thus,

- `column -t` will *consume memory proportional to the input size*, whereas `awk` will use a *constant amount of memory*.
- `column -t` is *typically slower*, depending on the Awk implementation used; `mawk` is much faster, `gawk` a little faster, BSD `awk` is slower(!); results based on a 10-million line input file; commands run on OSX 10.10.2 and Ubuntu 14.04.